# Why didn't the KSI design Galvatron from Sentinel Prime?

Tags: movie, transformers, optimus-prime

In the fourth Transformers movie, the Age of Extinction, it was shown that the KSI tried to create galvatron with designs from Optimus Prime. They did not have any specimen of the great Autobot leader to use for the development for he was still alive and in hiding. So they turned to what they got, and used Megatron's corpse to create Galvatron and in turn allowed Megatron to live in another body.

So the question is, if they have access to all and every battle scrap from Chicago, why didn't the KSI copied the coding and AI from Sentinel Prime instead of Optimus Prime for maximum similarity to Optimus? After all, they share traits of leadership and bravery, unlike Megatron.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simply the fact that KSI just see the remains as materials, which they are refashioning to their own ends.

They had used the other transformer remains including Sentinel Prime, Ratchet etc to build the various drones such as Stinger. 
All of these drones kept the shape they were given. 
Megatron's mind, unlike the others was still active. It is this still active mind that is refashioning the body from what they want to one more like Megatron.

The only one that knew that Megatron's brain was still active was Brains, who, probably due to his anger at being imprisoned wasn't in any mood to share with KSI.